# Showing that $\phi:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is injective

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to show that

$$\phi:(x,y)\to(\sin\frac{y}{2}-x, \sin\frac{x}{2}-y)$$

Is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. So, I need to show it's injective. How can I do this? Just explicitly setting $\phi(x, y)=\phi(x', y')$ just leads to a non-linear system that I can't even begin to solve. Is there some trick for showing that a multivariable function is injective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solving $\phi(x,y) = \phi(x',y')$ is easier than it looks. You get the pair of equations
$$
\sin \frac{y'}2 - x' = \sin \frac y2 - x, \quad \sin \frac{x'}2 - y' = \sin \frac x2 - y
$$
Look at the first equation. It leads to
$$ |x - x'| = \left| \sin \frac y2 - \sin \frac{y'}2 \right|
$$
Since the sine function is Lipschitz with constant $1$ you obtain $|x - x'| \le \dfrac 12 |y - y'|$.

Use the same argument with the other equation, and conclude $x = x'$ and $y = y'$.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose your function into
$$
\phi' : (x,y) \to (x-\sin\frac{y}{2}, y-\sin\frac{x}{2})
$$
and the reflection through origin.

Now $\phi'$ is the identity with a small periodic perturbation, so you only need to check that the perturbation is not enough to break injectivity (hint: partial derivatives of the perturbation are almost everywhere less than 1 in absolute value).